# Can Kafka Stream app read from Kinesis stream?

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, amazon-kinesis

I need to write a java app that reads from Kinesis stream and stores data to Kafka topic. I can not use the connector, I have to use Kafka Streams because there is a lot of logic involved. Can Kafka Stream read directly from Kinesis stream or I have to store data first to Kafka topic in order to be read by Kafka Stream?

I read a lot about Kafka Streams and I have never seen an example that Kafka Stream reads from something else except Kafka topic.

Answer (score 2):

Kafka Streams only connect to a single Kafka cluster and read/write topic. It cannot read from or write to any other system.

If we want to get data into Kafka (or export it from Kafka) you can use Kafka Connect. For simple data transformation, Connect offers so-called "single message transforms" (SMTs) that you can use. For more complex transformation, you will need to import the data unmodified first, and than use Kafka Streams to transform it accordingly.

Comment: Thank you so much Matthias for the thorough answer!